# AMD GPU Render on Ubuntu

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I use Blender 2.79 on Ubuntu 16.04 with an AMD Radeon RX 560 GPU. However, Blender doesn't detect my GPU as a "Cycels Compute Device". My approach is listed below:

1. Installation of Ubuntu 16.04
2. Installation of AMD GPU driver

My terminal output from  is:

```
*-display

description: VGA compatible controller
product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: cf
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: **driver=amdgpu** latency=0
resources: irq:26 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:efe00000-efffffff ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:fba80000-fbabffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

3. Download Blender 2.79 from Blender.org
4. Open the *Blender User Preferences*

   The System Tab in the window *Blender User Preferences* displays *None* as the *Cycles Compute Device*.

I am not shure whether I'm doing somthing wrong or whether it is a bug.
I would appreciate any help on this subject because I would like to render with my GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Install OpenCl Packages.

For Arch Linux: libopencl and opencl-amd